# Chart.js - How to put labels instead of tooltips?

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular-chart

I've been scanning the documentation of Chart.js and I can't seem to find 
if it is possible to add labels instead of tooltips for graph data
like the years on the image below (vertical texts):
[image]
Currently, I have this:
[image]
If this is possible, how to do so in Angular?

Comment: So, you have 8 series, one for each year, and the x values are months, and you want the series name to appear under each year, alongside the existing label (the month)?

Comment: Yes that's right. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, with effort. Tooltips are not built to be labels, but labels can be customized. If your bars were not so narrow, you could use nesting in the `labels` property to get multiple lines. Here though, that would mean replacing '1月' with [['2  2  2'],['0  0  0'],['1  1  1'],['2  3  4'],['年年年'],['1月']] just for the first three columns in your graph and it would break on resize. That leads me to a plugin: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/labels.html#dataset-overrides - you could add a custom label for each dataset. No time to try it out or I would answer.